# redirecting subdomain to parent domain in .htaccess

Tags: linux, .htaccess

I have a list of subdomains I need redirected to the parent domain but not sure how to setup the redirects in the .htaccess.

How would I redirect :

- http://subdomain.example.com/somepage

to

- http://example.com/somepage in my .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

To redirect

- http://subdomain.example.com/somepage

to

- http://example.com/somepage

add the following rule to your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?somepage http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,NC,R,L]
```

Comment: Do I have to setup the subdomains in order for this to work?

Comment: This kind of works but doesnt redirect to the correct page:

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tips\.silvercross\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.tips\.silvercross\.com$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.silvercross\.com\/" [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto your subdomain folder
2. Create .htaccess file in this folder

now copy and paste this code:

```
Redirect 301 /login http://example.com/somepage
```